# Where is "${path}/tmp" pointing in php.ini

Tags: php, easyphp

My phpmyadmin on a USB drive (I'm using EasyPHP Wamp ) is giving the following:

```
phpMyAdmin - Error
Cannot start session without errors, please check errors given in your PHP and/or webserver log   file and configure your PHP installation properly.
```

following [Cannot start session without errors in phpMyAdmin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5013118/cannot-start-session-without-errors-in-phpmyadmin)

I have cleared my browser cache, but its still not working. Now I want to check where session.save_path points to. In php.ini I see

```
session.save_path = "${path}/tmp"
```

I have my wamp on a USB key named F:. does the above in this context mean F:/tmp ?

Comment: AFAIK `${path}` doesn't get expanded nativly. there must be something else running on top of it to creating a final ini file when the server starts