# PHP sessions not working on CentOS with phpMyAdmin

Tags: php, session, phpmyadmin, centos, redhat

Can't login to phpmyadmin complains about sessions. I've set session.save_path to /var/lib/php/session and I've given this file 777 permissions.

Here is the full error I'm getting:

```
Cannot start session without errors, please check errors given in your PHP
and/or webserver log file and configure your PHP installation properly.
Also ensure that cookies are enabled in your browser.
```

I've also checked my web server logs and php error logs and there's nothing there.

I've also tried clearing my browser's cache & cookies multiple times to no avail.

Any help much appreciated!

Comment: `please check errors given in your PHP and/or webserver log file` Well, what does that say?

Comment: I did check my logs and there's nothing there apart from timezone warning which a fixed

Comment: possible duplicate of [Cannot start session without errors in phpMyAdmin](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5013118/cannot-start-session-without-errors-in-phpmyadmin)

Comment: "I've given this file 777 permissions." You mean you've given this folder permissions, correct?

Comment: I've solved it. I had to install PHP 5.3 rather than 5.4

Answer (score 0):

The problem was due to using PHP 5.4 which wasn't the official version in the repo. I've uninstalled 5.4 and installed 5.3 and now everything seems to work fine.