# Cannot start session without errors in phpMyAdmin, session variables don't work

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

First, I have already looked at rciiipo's [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5013118/cannot-start-session-without-errors-in-phpmyadmin) from 2011. My problem don't seem to be fixed with the answers provided, and I have a few other inputs.

I get the below error when pointing browser to phpMyAdmin

```
Cannot start session without errors, please check errors given in 
your PHP and/or webserver log file and configure your PHP installation properly.
Also ensure that cookies are enabled in your browser.
```

1) Session variables don't work with any php file. I am little unsure if it is related, but i believe the one problem causes the other.

This code below should display "teddy" when i refresh the webpage:

```
<?php
session_start();

$username = $_SESSION['username'];
if(isset($_SESSION['logged']) && $_SESSION['logged']=='yes') {
    echo "$username";
}   

$_SESSION['username']='Teddy';
$_SESSION['logged']='yes';
?>
```

My php.ini file:

```
session.save_path = "/var/lib/php5/session"
```

Permissions:

```
drwxr-xr-t  4 root www-data 4096 Sep  1 08:40 php5
  |
  -- drwxr-xr-x  2 root www-data 4096 Sep  1 08:40 session
```

I think the problem can be fixed if I only get $_SESSION variables to work in php.

Comment: it looks like you have wrong permission for `/var/lib/php5/session` it should be `drwxrwxr-t` or `dr-xrwxr-t` (assuming `www-data` is the web server user). Write permission is required in the directory to save session data.

Comment: Yes, thats all it needed. Why is that?

Comment: PHP stores the session data to the session.save_path and as PHP is being executed by web server, it runs on the web server's user. That is why the web server user needs write permission to the folder.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I agree with [bansi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2522554/bansi):

> it looks like you have wrong permission for /var/lib/php5/session it
>   should be drwxrwxr-t or dr-xrwxr-t (assuming www-data is the web
>   server user). Write permission is required in the directory to save
>   session data.

Also, you should check the log files in /var/log/ of PHP (and maybe Apache as well) - they might give you some more details...