# phpMyAdmin: How to solve "Error during session start" error?

Tags: phpmyadmin

My environment: Windows 8.1, php5.5, Apache 2.4, Firefox 45.1

```
phpMyAdmin - Error

Error during session start; please check your PHP and/or webserver log file and configure your PHP installation properly. Also ensure that cookies are enabled in your browser.

Ignoring unsupported language code.
```

I searched for hours, I did the following:

Clear browser cache and server session folder, it works at first. After get in to setup page or try to login, this error comes up again. And then I can't open the index.php

I also set my folder's authority so that all possible users can have all access to that folder and the contents in that folder, it doesn't work

I also changed some session config, not work.

phpinfo() shows correctly, php related extensions are enabled correctly.

I also checked log, both server and php log doesn't show the error logs at the time the issue happens.

Please help.

---

a part of php.ini:

```
doc_root = "F:\share\myprivate_server"
session.save_handler = files
session.save_path = "F:\share\myprivate_server\session"
session.use_strict_mode = 0
session.use_cookies = 1
session.use_only_cookies = 1
session.name = PHPSESSID
session.auto_start = 0
session.cookie_lifetime = 0
session.cookie_path = /
session.cookie_domain =
session.cookie_httponly =
session.serialize_handler = php
session.gc_probability = 1
session.gc_divisor = 1000
session.gc_maxlifetime = 1440
session.referer_check =
session.cache_limiter = nocache
session.cache_expire = 180
session.use_trans_sid = 0
session.hash_function = 0
session.hash_bits_per_character = 5
url_rewriter.tags = "a=href,area=href,frame=src,input=src,form=fakeentry"
```

---

a part of httpd.conf

```
DocumentRoot "F:/share/myprivate_server"
<Directory "/*">
  Options All
  Require all granted
  AllowOverride All
</Directory>

<Directory "/">
  Options All
  Require all granted
  AllowOverride All
</Directory>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cannot start session without errors in phpMyAdmin, session variables don't work](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25600461/cannot-start-session-without-errors-in-phpmyadmin-session-variables-dont-work)

Comment: I think that `Ignoring unsupported language code.` is just a warning message. The main problem is in session variables, I added a link in previous comment.

Answer (score 0):

I was looking at `Ignoring unsupported language code.`

Can you just change the language to English and see does it work?