# phpmyadmin error "Cannot start session without errors"

Tags: php, linux, phpmyadmin

after installing php5.5 phpmyadmin not working

phpMyAdmin - Error
Cannot start session without errors, please check errors given in your PHP and/or webserver log file and configure your PHP installation properly.

i have checked sessions.save_path = "/tmp" in php.ini and changed the chmod to 777

i don't now if this can help

phpmyadmin.noarch                                                                          2.11.11.3-2.el5.rf                                                                          @rpmforge

any one can help please

Comment: Gotta love the error though. “Cannot start session without errors”, that's just pure gold. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5013118/cannot-start-session-without-errors-in-phpmyadmin). It may help.

Comment: what can i do to fix this @AndreiP. ?

Comment: I left you a link. Click it! it's the(hehe) this word.

Comment: i have tried this solution not working with me

Comment: Did this configuration work properly prior to upgrading your PHP to 5.5? Do you recall which PHP version you were running before installing 5.5?

Comment: PHP 5.5 working fine, it was 5.3.